# Is it possible to disable the placeholder feature in mat form fields?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using Angular 5 and compatible Angular Material.

I want to change the font-size of mat-form-field's input, but when I do so the text area grows taller than expected, due to the placeholder having to fit above the input area.

So, is there a way to completely disable the placeholder feature?

Comment: What happens if you simply don't provide a placeholder?

Comment: The text area is still much taller than usual because it expects a placeholder even if I don't give it one.

Comment: You can override the `border-top` CSS property to `none` on the `.mat-form-field-infix` class? That will remove the extra spacing at the top.

Comment: Beautiful, that more or less works. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [`floatLabel="never"`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#floating-label)? Posting this as a comment as I'm not sure it would make the kind of difference you're expecting, but that's supposed to disable the placeholder area above the field.

Comment: border-top: none worked better for me, but i appreciate the options